# How do I change \marginfont size and style without changing justification?

Tags: memoir, marginnote

I am using the Memoir class (two-sided) and `marginnote`. I want to change the font size to `scriptsize` (all the time) and the style to italic (all the time) for marginnotes. When I use the following command:

`\renewcommand\marginnote{\normalfont\scriptsize}`

The text changes to scriptsize and the margins for the marginnotes stay the same (for two-sided: left marginnotes are raggedleft, center justified; right marginnotes are raggedright, center justified). But, if I try adding `\textit` to the `\renewcommand` string (or using `textit` in any way, such as dropping `\normalfont\scriptsize` and replacing it with `textit`), I don't get italic text (the font style does change) and the margins of the marginnotes go haywire (as in, they revert to normal paragraph justification starting with an indent).

[image]

I'm sure the solution is simple (newbie), but the same type of problem crops up frequently so I'm hoping to gain some deeper knowledge about what goes wrong when I attempt what the manual suggests is a simple change.

This is an MWE:

```
    \documentclass[letterpaper,twoside]{memoir}
    \usepackage{marginnote}

    \renewcommand\marginfont{%
        \normalfont\scriptsize
    }

    \begin{document}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean porta nunc lorem, in efficitur diam posuere quis. Morbi in sapien nec purus iaculis fermentum quis vel dui. Donec id orci eu lectus pulvinar ullamcorper eu in metus. Suspendisse risus velit, pharetra sed auctor non, volutpat id dui. Nunc feugiat magna sed dolor posuere, non eleifend sapien posuere. \marginnote{This is a long enough for the text to wrap.}Nam eu iaculis leo, sed pulvinar tellus. Phasellus finibus ipsum vel nibh sollicitudin, in semper quam tempor. Quisque id purus est. Curabitur mauris turpis, finibus eget efficitur a, auctor in ligula. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed porta, lacus sed bibendum auctor, mauris nisl porta risus, quis facilisis urna mauris nec massa. Fusce fringilla ipsum at ante fermentum volutpat vitae id nisi. Nam faucibus lorem mollis metus sodales fringilla. Quisque efficitur aliquet ipsum at bibendum. Maecenas nec libero hendrerit, cursus ante sit amet, interdum nisi.

    \newpage

    Cras molestie blandit convallis. Donec a diam porta massa lobortis vulputate in id tellus. Vivamus dignissim ut mi eu egestas. Nam aliquet ultricies porta. \marginnote{This is a long enough for the text to wrap.}Pellentesque sit amet enim ut mauris accumsan tristique vel posuere lorem. Cras ut tincidunt arcu. Aliquam porttitor sed massa ut pellentesque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse hendrerit enim quis commodo rhoncus.

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access *italic text* via a **command** like

```
\textit{<italic text>}
```

or via a **switch** using

```
\itshape <italic text>
```

Typically the latter is used within some *scope*, as in

```
<regular text> {\itshape <italic text>} <regular text>
```

However, since your scope is predefined to the margin, you don't really need this. As such, I'd go with

```
\renewcommand\marginfont{%
    \normalfont\scriptsize\itshape
}
```